# Django admin: Prefetch choices in list_editable

Tags: python, sql, django, django-admin

I have a model `Domain` and I set it's `ForeignKey` Language model in `list_editable` in `ModelAdmin`.

The problem is that it causes lot of `SQL` queries according to `django_debug_toolbar`. I thought that I could solve it using `select_related` but it did not help because it selects only actual values, not all choices.

```
@register(Domain)
class DomainAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'main_url', 'language', 'max_depth', 'number_of_urls']
    list_editable = ['name', 'main_url', 'language', 'max_depth']
    list_select_related = ['language']

    #def get_queryset(self, request):
    #    return super(DomainAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('language')
```

It still perform `SQL` query for every `Domain` to fetch all `Language` objects.

[image]

How to make it fetch once for all `Domain`s?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same problem and made it for list, but not for change or add views in admin

Comment: This can helps in some cases ModelAdmin.list_per_page = 10

Answer (score 2):

`Django-cachalot is especially efficient in the Django administration website since it’s unfortunately badly optimised (use foreign keys in list_editable if you need to be convinced).`

https://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html